# Bash scripts return a substring not whole value in column for psql

Tags: bash, psql

I want to get the value of message in db, which for example is "the error is missing index " but when I run the code belong, it only return me 'the' for error_type. How could this happen that only return me the first word but not the whole value of the query result? How can I get the query results with the whole value?

```
declare -a ROW=($(psql \
    -X \
    -U $DB_USER \
    -h $DB_HOST \
    -d $DB_NAME \
    -p $DB_PORT \
    --single-transaction \
    --set AUTOCOMMIT=off \
    --set ON_ERROR_STOP=on \
    --no-align \
    -t \
    --field-separator ' ' \
    --quiet \
    -c "SELECT message
        FROM error_message
        WHERE created_at > '$t1' and created_at < '$t'")
)

error_type=${ROW[0]}
echo $error_type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an array, use an ordinary string variable to contain the whole result.

```
error_type=$(psql \
    -X \
    -U $DB_USER \
    -h $DB_HOST \
    -d $DB_NAME \
    -p $DB_PORT \
    --single-transaction \
    --set AUTOCOMMIT=off \
    --set ON_ERROR_STOP=on \
    --no-align \
    -t \
    --field-separator ' ' \
    --quiet \
    -c "SELECT message
        FROM error_message
        WHERE created_at > '$t1' and created_at < '$t'")

echo "$error_type"
```

Remember to quote variables unless you need word splitting and wildcard expansion to be done.

Comment: Thank you!! And do you know if I want to select multiple columns' value, should I use an array?

Comment: Then you'll have to work harder because you need to separate the columns differently from words in the columns. You could use TAB as the field separator, then use `IFS` to split the output using tabs into array elements.

Comment: And if the query returns multiple rows, you will need to use a loop to read each line.